# Changing a nominal variable to remove one particular label with zero instances in weka

Tags: weka

I have a very simple questions, but I am all confused with the user interface, and I could not find it in the documentation.

I have a feature in my dataset that is nominal. It used to have 4 classes but I deleted the instances of one class. Now I want to classify based on this feature.

BUT, in the preprocess window, the attribute is still listed as having 4 classes, of which one has 0 instances. It performs the classification as it should, but in the result, there is a column/row in the confusion matrix and accuracy table for the zero class.

Is there a way to remove the label with zero instances, zo weka thinks that the feature only has three values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it. I opened the weka file in an editor. There I could change the feature definition.